# How to auto generate IdentityModels.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm updating my knowledge within ASP.NET MVC Code First. I have not used it for some time and it seems like I have forgot some knowledge.

I have done a project with a couple of models, controllers and views. When I compare this new project with other projects that I have done earlier, I don't have this line of code in the controllers

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

And I don't have this file inside the of the Models folder:

```
 IdentityModels.cs
```

I guess those are auto generated in some ways, but what could I have done wrong, since I don't have these files?

My project and application is working because instead of the code above I have similar code like this:

```
private ViewModelTest1Context db = new ViewModelTest1Context();
```

and `ViewModelTest1Context.cs`

But why the difference in names?

Comment: What kind of authentication did you select when creating the project?

Comment: @Alexander I selected the No Authentication, perhaps that could be the reason? I guess it's not any wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to select "Individual Accounts" to get it.

Comment: Yes: "No Authentication" will _not_ generate that file, which contains those classes.

Comment: OK! Thanks for all comments! Then I guess it's normal to get other names of this code?